# Looking for the Big Commerce Global Variable Name that Returns instock and oos (Out of Stock) Values

Tags: global-variables, bigcommerce

I am looking for the Global Variable in the Big Commerce Store that will return me the instock and oos values. Can someone help me identify...I already have the following that returns me the global product price:

"%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%%GLOBAL_InventoryList%%
```

will output the current stock level. You can easily find this in the same file as your price, ProductAddToCart.html along with quite a few other variables.

Comment: @Musti no problem. Remember to mark this as a correct answer so that the question is resolved.